# PHP rest service

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to PHP and i'm trying to send this of to a webservice.

```
<?php
$myID = "8125987";
$myVarible = "This is a test";
$service_url = "https://...?password=123&user=123&storeid=1000&mobile=$myID&message=$myVarible";
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
?>
```

It is not working, what is wrong?
Thanks for any help.
KHJ

Comment: "It's not working" is a useless phrase.  If you want to troubleshoot, you need to define the problem.  What happens? Are there errors? (If not, are you sure error reporting is on?) What do you get when you `var_dump($result)`? etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Check if your curl function exists first

> echo function_exists('curl_version') ? 1:0; // 1 = enabled , 0 =
>   disabled.

### 2) Try to access example.com instead of your target url

> $url = "http://www.example.com";

### 3) Print out the curl info and err message before you asked a question

> There're lots of CURL examples on the internet, however, I still did one for your reference.
>   https://www.stockeasymoney.com/ns/sit/curlRaw.php

```
<?php
    echo function_exists('curl_version') ? 1:0; // 1 = enabled , 0 = disabled.

    echo "<pre>";
    $url = "http://www.example.com";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r( curl_getinfo($ch) );

    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```